# Complicated "conditional sentences"

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

A lottery seller said to me:

> If you win the round, a TV set will be the prize you **will be** winning.

My mother said to me:

> If you had stayed in England, it would be the fifth year you **were** learning English.

Are these darkened **auxiliary verbs** correct?

Comment: No. It's *...the prize you **will win***, and *the fifth year you **would have been learning** English*. Except in some rather contrived contexts.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The sentences are both syntactically correct. There is nothing actually *wrong* with *a TV set will be the prize you will be winning*. However, it's not idiomatic. And if I were rephrasing it, on the grounds of it sounding natural, I would personally say *the prize you* ***win***, or, even better, *If you win the round, a TV set will be* ***your prize***.

Comment: @JasonBassford what about the second one?

Comment: @Kumarsadhu Perhaps *if you had stayed in England, **this** would be **your** fifth year of learning English.* But I don't see how these rephrased sentences are helping with your actual question. Aside, maybe, from pointing out that your use of auxiliary verbs aren't being used in entirely natural constructions.

Comment: @JasonBassford: I never suggested there was any *syntactic* "error". Quite the reverse, since I specifically said that OP's versions could actually be *preferred* in certain [contrived?] contexts. But in most contexts, OP's choice of continuous tense forms here will simply come across as typical "Indian English" usages that mainstream Anglophones rarely come out with (to us, they're "marked" forms). The second example is pretty complex though, just because of the hypothetical scenario being contemplated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that's exactly what I said. You're talking about what sounds natural, not what is syntactically correct. And if you're going to talk about what sounds natural, and are going to rephrase it on that ground, I think it could be rephrased in an even better way.

Comment: @JasonBassford: You miss my point. I'm not really concerned with entering a "beauty contest" for the "most natural phrasing" - just saying that "future continuous" is highly unlikely for the first example (except to "Indian English" speakers). For "idiomacy", I'd go for *...the fifth year **of** learning English* in the second case, but that's getting somewhat Off-Topic / POB.

Comment: Could you guys please answer it giving the grammatical rules